# NSArrayController backed array modification in background thread

Tags: multithreading, cocoa, binding, nsarraycontroller

Here is the situation:

- NSTableView bound to a NSArrayController
- NSArrayController bound to an array of AnalysisResult objects

  ```
  dynamic var analysisResults: [AnalysisResult] = [AnalysisResult]() // model for table view via resultsArrayController
  ```
- The NSTableView has a column "result" bound to AnalysisResult.value

Now when the user clicks on a button, it triggers an analysis in a background thread, and modifies the objects in "analysisResults". It does NOT add nor remove any object from the array. It just changes the "value" property of the AnalysisResult objects.

```
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
        for (index, curAnalysisRes) in self.analysisResults.enumerate() {
            curAnalysisRes.value = "some new value" // simplified but the value can be updated in many different places of the algorithm
        }
        dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            /* Ask the tableview to reload data in main UI thread */
            self.myTableView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

After the analysis, the UI thread is asked to update the table view.

BUT here is the problem: I get the following warning:

```
  CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction; created by:
  0   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff8f06369a _ZN2CA11Transaction4pushEv + 318
  1   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff8f06319a _ZN2CA11Transaction15ensure_implicitEv + 276
  2   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff8f069719 _ZN2CA5Layer13thread_flags_EPNS_11TransactionE + 37
  3   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff8f069668 _ZN2CA5Layer4markEPNS_11TransactionEjj + 64
  4   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff8f06b12b _ZN2CA5Layer25set_needs_display_in_rectERK6CGRect + 333
  5   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff8f06afdc -[CALayer setNeedsDisplayInRect:] + 25
  6   AppKit                              0x00007fff872d12e8 _NSBackingLayerSetNeedsDisplayInRect + 319
  7   AppKit                              0x00007fff872d11a3 -[_NSBackingLayer setNeedsDisplayInRect:] + 61
  8   QuartzCore                          0x00007fff8f06af9d -[CALayer setNeedsDisplay] + 62
  9   AppKit                              0x00007fff872d198b -[NSView(NSInternal) _setLayerNeedsDisplayInViewRect:] + 606
  10  AppKit                              0x00007fff8729f88e NSViewSetNeedsDisplayInRect + 945
  11  AppKit                              0x00007fff8729f4d6 -[NSView setNeedsDisplayInRect:] + 48
  12  AppKit                              0x00007fff8729f2ed -[NSView setNeedsDisplay:] + 81
  13  AppKit                              0x00007fff872f2be1 -[NSTextFieldCell setObjectValue:] + 88
  14  AppKit                              0x00007fff873e3026 -[NSControl setObjectValue:] + 135
  15  AppKit                              0x00007fff873ce0c6 -[_NSPlaceholderTextFieldPlugin showValue:inObject:] + 110
```

The warning is caused by modifying the array bound to the arraycontroller.
I do not want to perform the analysis in the main thread because it freezes the UI.

How can I avoid the warning?

Answer (score 0):

OK I have found the solution here, and it was pretty straightforward.

Since I was modifying the values of the array bound to the NSArrayController and since the controller is bound to a NSTableView (thus UI-related), I was obviously doing UI-stuff not in the main UI thread.

Technically speaking, since cocoa bindings use KVO (key-value observing), the change notifications triggered by my modifications in the array, were propagated in a non-UI thread, causing the up-mentionned message:

```
CoreAnimation: warning, deleted thread with uncommitted CATransaction;
```

Furthermore, an interesting side-effect, the piece of code:

```
self.myTableView.reloadData()
```

is not necessary anymore because the KVO notifications now propagate properly in the UI-thread.